# Finding infinitely many solutions to an ODE (Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

The ODE given is described in the following way:

> $y'(t)$ = $\sqrt{|y(t)|}$
>              $y(0)$ = $0$.

The question asks us to point out infinitely many solutions to the ODE, and further to prove whether or not a unique solution exists if we assume $y(t)$ > $0$ for all $t\neq 0$.

I'm sure this isn't an extremely difficult question, but I'm unsure how to begin...

Comment: I may be confused here, but just evaluating $y'(0) = \sqrt{|y(0)|} = 0$ implies that it will not change so $y(t) \equiv 0$ for all $t \ge 0$ with that initial condition.

Comment: square both sides than differentiate

Comment: @AsharTafhim using this method I'm getting only that y''(t) = 1/2....does this simply mean that any y(t) which gives y''(t) = 1/2 is a solution?

Comment: y'(2y''-1)=0 does not imply y''=1/2 always, there may be points with y'=0.

Comment: @mathematician ahhh, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since the equation is nonlinear, there is no guarantee of uniqueness. Following you question, we can suppose $y(t) > 0$ for all $|t| > 0$. Then we can simply solve this as a separable system
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dt} & = y^{1/2} \\
\int \frac{dy}{y^{1/2}} & = \int dt \\
2y^{1/2} & = t + C \\
y(t) & = \frac{1}{4}(t + C)^2.
\end{align}
Using the initial condition we obtain $y(t) = \frac{1}{4} t^2$. Similarly, if $y(t) < 0$ for all $|t|>0$ we would $y(t) = - \frac{1}{4} t^2$. And finally if no restriction is placed $y(t) \equiv 0$ is a solution as well.

**Edit:** The additional constraints that $y(t) > 0$ for $|t| > 0$ yields a unique solution for this problem (an analogous result holds when $y(t)$ is nonpositive).

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you! Assuming $y(t)$ > 0 is actually another part of the question in which it asks if there is a unique solution (no).

Would we solve this in a similar way if we don't assume $y(t)$ > 0? That is, instead of saying $dy/dt$ = $y^{1/2}$ we say that $+/-(dy/dt)^2$ = $y$?

Comment: This example does prove uniqueness assuming y(t)>0.  The other solutions are that y(t) is identically 0 on an interval, then grows quadratically (in + or - direction) as in this example.

Comment: @mathematician, you're of course correct. I updated the solution, thanks.

Comment: @mizichael, I was corrected that the requirement that $y > 0$ forces a unique solution in this case, namely $y(t) = 0$ for all $t$ of course can't be a solution when $y > 0$ is imposed.